# Consequence of Cauchy Integral Formula for Several Complex Variables in Gunning's book

Tags: several-complex-variables

I am reading Gunning's book Introduction to Holomorphic Functions of Several Variables, Vol. I, and I am stuck in the proof of Maximum modulus theorem: if $f$ is holomorphic in a connected open subset $D \subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$ and if there is a point $A \in D$ such that $|f(Z)| \leq |f(A)|$ for all points $Z$ in some open neighborhood of $A$, then $f(Z) = f(A)$ for all points $Z \in D$. In the proof Gunning says that for any polydisc $\Delta = \Delta(A; R) \subset D$ for which $\overline{\Delta} \subset D$ we have as a consequence of the Cauchy integral formula that

$$|\Delta| f(A) = \int_{\Delta} f(Z) dV(Z),$$
where $dV(Z)$ is the Euclidean volume element in $\mathbb{C}^{n} = \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and $|\Delta| = \int_{\Delta} dV(Z) = \pi^{n}r_{1}^{2} \cdots r_{n}^{2}$ is the Euclidean volume of $\Delta$.

It looks very easy, but I am stuck on it for a long time. I can not see how this is a consequence of Cauchy integral formula, since the integral is on $\Delta$ and not on the product of $|\zeta_{j} - a_{j}| = r_{j}$. We can not apply Stokes, because the form is of degree $n$. Maybe the Intermediate Value Theorem for integrals solve it, but how to assure that the point giving the equality is $A$? Maybe a change of variables?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an *integrated* form of the Cauchy formula. The single complex variable case illustrates what's going on. For example,
$$
f(0) = {1\over 2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} {f(z)\over z}\;dz
= {1\over 2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} {f(re^{i\theta})\over r\,e^{i\theta}}\,d(re^{i\theta})
= {1\over 2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(re^{i\theta})\;i\,d\theta
$$
can be integrated (for example) $\int_0^1 \ldots r\,dr$:
$$
f(0)\cdot \int_0^11\cdot r\,dr \;=\; {1\over 2\pi}\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}
f(re^{i\theta})\;r\;d\theta\,dr
$$
The obvious absolute-value estimate gives
$$
|f(0)|\;\le\; {1\over \pi} \int_{|z|\le 1} |f(z)|\,dV
$$